# CLR 2.0 memory leak: Failing to release COM object on unload

Tags: memory-leaks, clr, com-interop, managed-c++

I have come across a bug in CLR 2.0 that is resolved in CLR 4.0. It occurs when passing arrays across .NET COM interop and a COM exception is generated (E_FAIL). The details of how to reproduce this bug are below.

My problem is that it will be very difficult to force our clients to upgrade to .NET 4.0, so I'd like to implement a workaround. I can do so by calling obj->Release if I know that the bug has occured, but clearly this is dangerous if there's any chance of a false positive.

And so the question: What is the specification of this bug, and is it possible for me to identify it precisely?

I found .NET release notes for 4.0.1, 4.0.2, and 4.0.3, but the bug is not mentioned. There must be a significant changelist in the CLR transition from 2.0 to 4.0, and I guess this is not publicly available?

Obviously the code below makes little sense on its own, but it's the simplest reproduction of the issue that I could distill based on quite a large, complicated solution.

Thanks in advance for taking a look,

R

**Important Edit**

Unfortunately, I came back to try and investigate a little further, and it's possible that the code below does not actually reproduce the bug, which would be disappointing. However, in the actual application, the memory leak is clear. If someone is interested and I have time, I'll try to produce a valid example.

**Code Overview**

I have a .NET application, ConsoleApp.exe, here reproduced in C# although the original is F#. ConsoleApp.exe calls a managed assembly, managed.AComObject.dll, that exposes a COM object, AComObject. AComObject.get_TheObject() returns a VARIANT* pointing to a smart pointer, ASmartPtr, which allows me to override the AddRef and Release methods to observe the references held against the object.

When running ConsoleApp.exe with unmanaged code debugging enabled, I can see the reference counts on the SmartPtr. I change the CLR by adjusting the supportedRuntime property in ConsoleApp.exe.config with the following results:

- v4.0 shows "DEBUGMSG::ASmartPtr::Release:0", at which point the SmartPtr is deleted.
- v2.0.50727 shows "DEBUGMSG::ASmartPtr::Release:1" before it exits, a leak.

I include the bits of code I believe are relevant, but please shout if more is required; COM needs a lot of boilerplate code...!

**ConsoleApp.exe**

```
using managed.AComObject;
using System;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AComObject an_obj = new AComObject();
        object[] pData = new object[] { 1 };
        object a_val = an_obj.get_TheObject(0, pData);
        object[] pData2 = new object[] { a_val };

        try
        {
            object obj3 = an_obj.get_TheObject(1, pData2);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            // Makes no diff whether it's caught - still does not clean
        }
    }
}
```

**AComObject.dll**

*AComObject.idl*

```
interface IAComObject : IDispatch
{
    [propget, id(1), helpstring("")] HRESULT DllName([out, retval] BSTR* pName);
    [propget, id(2), helpstring("")] HRESULT TheObject([in] LONG count, [in, size_is(count)] VARIANT* pData, [out, retval] VARIANT* pObject);
};

[...]    
library AComObjectLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    // Class information
    [...]
    coclass AComObject
    {
        [default] interface IAComObject;
    };
};
```

AComObject.h

```
[...]

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CAComObject :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CAComObject, &CLSID_AComObject>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IAComObject, &IID_IAComObject, &LIBID_AComObjectLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
{
public:
DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_ACOMOBJECT)

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CAComObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY2(IDispatch, IAComObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IAComObject)
END_COM_MAP()

public:
    CAComObject();

    virtual /* [helpstring][propget] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_DllName(
            /* [retval][out] */ BSTR* pName);

    virtual /* [helpstring][propget] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_TheObject(
            /* [in] */ LONG count,
            /* [in, size_is(count)] */ VARIANT* pData,
            /* [retval][out] */ VARIANT* pObject);
};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(CLSID_AComObject, CAComObject)
```

*AComObject.cpp*

```
class ASmartPtr : public IUnknown
{
    int m_RC;

    void DebugMsg(std::string msg)
    {
        std::stringstream _msg;
        _msg << ".\nDEBUGMSG::ASmartPtr::" << msg << "\n";
        OutputDebugStringA(_msg.str().c_str());
    }
public:
    ASmartPtr()
        : m_RC(1)
    {
        DebugMsg(std::string("Created"));
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() 
    {
        ULONG refcnt = ++m_RC;
        std::stringstream msg;
        msg << "AddRef:" << refcnt;
        DebugMsg(msg.str());
        return refcnt;
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() 
    {
        ULONG refcnt = --m_RC;
        std::stringstream msg;
        msg << "Release:" << refcnt;
        DebugMsg(msg.str());
        if (m_RC == 0)
            delete this;
        return refcnt;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppvObj)
    {
        if (!ppvObj) return E_POINTER;

        if (iid == IID_IUnknown)
        {
            *ppvObj = this;
            AddRef();
            return NOERROR;
        }
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
};

[...]

STDMETHODIMP CAComObject::get_TheObject(LONG count, VARIANT* pData, VARIANT* pObject)
{
    if (count == 1)
        return E_FAIL;

    CComVariant res;
    res.punkVal = new ASmartPtr();
    res.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;

    res.Detach(pObject);

    return S_OK;
}
```

**managed.AComObject.dll**

This is assembled from the COM object with the following post-build events to enable passing of arrays to get_TheObject() rather than references.

*Batch File*

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"

echo "f" | xcopy /L/D/Y ..\Debug\AComObject.dll  managed.AComObject.dll | find "AComObject" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    tlbimp   ..\Debug\AComObject.dll /primary /keyfile:..\piakey.snk /out:managed.AComObject.dll
  ildasm managed.AComObject.dll /out:managed.AComObject.raw.il
  perl -p oneliner.pl < managed.AComObject.raw.il > managed.AComObject.il
  ilasm managed.AComObject.il /dll /key=..\piakey.snk
)
set errorlevel=0
exit 0
```

*oneliner.pl*

```
$a = 1 if (/TheObject\(/);if ($a){s/object&/object\[\]/; s/marshal\( struct\) pData/marshal\( \[\]\) pData/; $a++; $a&=3;}
```

This simply changes the IL:

```
[in] object&  marshal( struct) pData) runtime managed internalcall
```

to

```
[in] object[]  marshal( []) pData) runtime managed internalcall
```

**Some additional information**

In considering my response to Hans's comment, I realised some relevant information is missing.

If no exception is thrown (i.e. E_FAIL is changed to S_OK), there is no leak. In the S_OK case, we can see the object reference count returning to 1 as we cross the .NET COM interop back into ConsoleApp.exe. In the E_FAIL case, the refcount remains at 2. In both cases, we can observe the finalizer reducing the refcount again as the application terminates (and observe the object destructor in the S_OK case), but in the E_FAIL case, this still leaves the refcount at 1 so the object is leaked. In CLR 4.0, all behaves as expected (i.e. refcount returns to 1 on passing back to ConsoleApp.exe even in the E_FAIL case).

We are considering upgrading to CLR 4.0 to resolve this leak, but it is not entirely trivial since it treats COM wrapped managed DLLs in a different way and this is a breaking change for some of our clients. If there was a way for me to precisely identify this bug, we could avoid the upgrade pain for a little longer.

Comment: The order in which the finalizer thread destroys RCWs is not deterministic.

Comment: That's true, but I think the object should be finally released and destroyed, and we should see that happen, even if we cannot determine when it is going to happen - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the solution was rather simple, and we were able to proceed without upgrading. It was the old trick of adding a supportedRuntime and the additional attribute to the application.exe.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Without the attribute, the .NET2 code loads side-by-side into CLR2, and so we suffer the leak. The attribute allows the .NET2 code to be loaded directly into the CLR4, hence avoiding the leak. There is a detailed review of that attribute here: http://www.marklio.com/marklio/PermaLink,guid,ecc34c3c-be44-4422-86b7-900900e451f9.aspx.

This unfortunately leaves the memory leak extant for anyone using an application with such a config, but this is adequate for the time being.

Comment: I thought you said that you could not force the client to upgrade to .net 4.0. Would they not have to have the .net 4.0 CLR installed on the machine for this to work?

Comment: Yes that is true. Unfortunately, clients will still suffer the leak if they are using CLR2, so in that sense the problem is not solved. I'll untick it.